# Converting DataGridView DataSource to DataSet

Tags: c++, datagridview, dataset, changetype

what I'm trying to achieve is to convert DataGridView->DataSource (System::Object) to DataSet in C++, eg.

```
DataSet^ MyData = Convert::ChangeType(dataGridView1->DataSource,DataSet::typeid);
```

I found this on: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/fca06da9-042e-4ee5-b495-358e8a6f44e9/

But this throws me an error:

> a value of type "System::Object ^" cannot be used to initialize an
>   entity of type "System::Data::DataSet ^"

Probably it's simple to fix, but nothing comes to my mind.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815131

Comment: I've seen this, but I didn't find an answer there.